# MAC address getting reset

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, 17.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 from Ubuntu 16.04. And I have a problem to connect to network with cloned MAC address.

I changed the address in usual way (I tried `ip link` and `ifconfig`) according to standard procedure - I check name of the device, shut it down, change address, set it up, check it. The address is changed successfully (I checked that with `ifconfig` and `ip link`) and the procedure worked at Ubuntu 16. However, if I try to connect to wired network, it fail and my MAC address is set back to original one.

Again, the used procedure was working on Ubuntu 16 correctly, the problem occur now on Ubuntu 17.

Comment: Your post is not clear. You change the MAC address and it fails to connect at all or does it fail only if you use wired? Or it works with wireless but fails and restores original when you connect to wired?

Comment: @jpezz Thanks for response! There is no word about wireless, because this pc does not have any wireless card.

Comment: After you change it, did you reboot or reset your router? It knows your old MAC address and has associated your IP with that MAC address.